# I cant save uniq value in Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, postgresql

i have following models:

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    seo_name = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
     vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, unique=False, blank=True, default=None, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

i make parser of xml file and in these file vendor set foreach position, i need save only unique values in vendor model, but for each product set his vendor , i make it like these:

```
for p in products:
    vendor = Vendor()
    vendor.name = p['vendor']
    try:
        vendor.save()
    except:
        pass
    product.vendor = vendor
```

The result is that in the model of the Product vendor assigned only to those values ​​when parsing that their vendor has not yet been saved.
The question is how to make sure that the vendor would be assigned to each product?

all code for cicle p in products:

```
def adversolution_aizel(xml_file):
    e = ET.parse(xml_file)
    d = etree_to_dict(e.getroot())
    shop_name = d['yml_catalog']['shop']['name']
    shop_company = d['yml_catalog']['shop']['company']
    shop_url = d['yml_catalog']['shop']['url']
    shop_attr = Shop()
    shop_attr.name = shop_name
    shop_attr.seo_name = shop_company
    shop_attr.import_url = shop_url
    try:
        shop_attr.save()
    except:
        pass

    products = d['yml_catalog']['shop']['offers']['offer']
    for p in products:
        product = Product()
        product.external_url = p['url']
        product.price = p['price']
        product.old_price = p['oldprice']
        product.currencies = p['currencyId']
        # product.category_id = p['categoryId']
        #############################################################################
        picture = Image()
        picture.external_img_url = p['picture']
        picture.save()
        product.picture = picture
        ##############################################################################
        product.name = p['name']
        ##############################################################################
        vendor = Vendor()
        vendor.name = p['vendor']
        try:
            vendor.save()
        except:
            pass
        product.vendor = vendor
        ##############################################################################
        product.shop = shop_name
        product.description = p['description']
        product.save()
```

Comment: Where is `product` coming from? Thanks.

Comment: i add all part of code, check pls

Comment: What if you would remove the try/except part - how would it fail?

Comment: if i remove try/except its gonna crach with Error coz i try save non-unique value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method for the vendor:

```
for p in products:
    product = Product()
    # ...

    vendor, _ = Vendor.objects.get_or_create(name=p['vendor'])
    product.vendor = vendor  # or product.vendor_id = vendor.id   

    product.shop = shop_name
    product.description = p['description']
    product.save()
```

Comment: i shod use it when try set product.vendor?

Comment: Can you edit my question and past your code in right place?

Comment: in these case i get ValueError: Cannot assign "(<Vendor: Agent Provocateur>, False)": "Product.vendor" must be a "Vendor" instance.

Comment: All work now, thank you, but can you explaine these moment:
 vendor, _  what is mean?

Comment: @AlexandrDomoryonok `_` is a throwaway variable - in this case it would receive a value of a boolean variable which means whether an object was created or an existing one was retrieved..see docs for the `get_or_create()` I've referred you to.

Comment: Thank you, it's really help me